# At no point vs. At any point

Tags: difference, determiners, negative-inversion

I wanted to know the difference between the following sentences and if they are both correct to use.

> 1. At no point was I told what the job involved.
> 2. At any point I wasn't told what the job involved.

Comment: The second version is invalid. There's an underlying "base" statement: *I was **not** told XXX **at any point***. Less idiomatically (with the negation shifted to the adverbial element): *I was told XXX **at no point***. We can make that second version idiomatic by "fronting" the negated adverbial element - but as per your first example, that requires "subject + verb inversion" *At **no** point **was I** told XXX*.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at Prof John Lawler's [Summary of Negative Polarity Items.](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, the "any" needs to go after the "not":

> 1. At no point was I told what the job involved.
> 2. I wasn't told what the job involved at any point.

These two versions mean the same thing. To me (1) sounds more idiomatic.